# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for the right syntax to use near ''&lt)' at line 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

#### DATABASE SERVER

**Server**: Localhost via UNIX socket
**Server type**: MySQL
**Server version**: 5.5.56-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
**Protocol version**: 10
**Server charset**: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

#### WEB SERVER

cpsrvd 11.66.0.18
**Database client version**: libmysql - 5.1.73
**PHP extension**: mysqli, curl, mbstring
**PHP version**: 5.6.30

#### phpMyAdmin

**Version information**: 4.7.3

I am using **phpMyAdmin** to update the column **text** which type is **text** with the following query:

```
UPDATE `oc_product_tab` SET `text` = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Ελλάδα:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΗ αποστολή - αφού έχει επιβεβαιωθεί η παραγγελία σας - πραγματοποιείτε &lt;strong&gt;σε όλη την Ελλάδα&lt;/strong&gt; με ταχυμεταφορά courier και η παράδοση γίνετε σε 1-3 εργάσιμες ημέρες στη διεύθυνση που θα δηλώσετε.&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΤο κόστος των μεταφορικών είναι &lt;strong&gt;3 ευρώ&lt;/strong&gt; για παραγγελίες κάτω των 15 ευρώ.&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&lt;strong&gt;Για παραγγελίες άνω των 15 ευρώ η αποστολή είναι δωρεάν Πανελλαδικά.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΣτις περιπτώσεις όπου η πληρωμή γίνεται με αντικαταβολή η &lt;strong&gt;χρέωση αντικαταβολής&lt;/strong&gt; είναι &lt;strong&gt;2€&lt;/strong&gt; επιπλέον.&lt;br /&gt;\r\n&lt;u&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Εξωτερικό:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΣε όλες τις χώρες της Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης η &lt;strong&gt;χρέωση&lt;/strong&gt; αποστολής είναι &lt;strong&gt;12€&lt;/strong&gt; για παραγγελία βάρους έως 3 κιλών ανεξαρτήτου της ποσότητας παραγγελίας και φτάνει στην πόρτα σας μεταξύ 5 έως 8 εργάσιμων ημερών.&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΓια παραγγελίες άνω των &lt;strong&gt;150€ εντός Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης&lt;/strong&gt; τα έξοδα αποστολής είναι &lt;strong&gt;ΔΩΡΕΑΝ!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\r\nΣτις υπόλοιπες χώρες η αποστολή γίνεται μέσω των δημόσιων ταχυδρομείων. Η χρέωση αποστολής καθώς και οι ημέρες παράδοσης εξαρτώνται από τη ζώνη αποστολής. Θα σας ενημερώσουμε μέσω e-mail ή τηλεφωνικά αφού ολοκληρώσετε τη διαδικασία παραγγελίας σας και πριν σας αποσταλούν τα εμπορεύματα.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n' WHERE `oc_product_tab`.`tab_id` = 2 AND `oc_product_tab`.`language_id` = 2;
```

and the error is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''&lt)' at line 1
```

I have changed the name of the column from **text** to **mytext** (because text is a reserved word for MySQL) and the error shows up again.

If I use this query:

```
UPDATE `oc_product_tab` SET `text` = '' WHERE `language_id` = 2 AND `tab_id` = 2
```

It works.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to escape the & character, maybe a few others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution I will stick with this query:

```
UPDATE `oc_product_tab` SET `text` = '<p><u><strong>Ελλάδα:</strong></u><br />Η αποστολή - αφού έχει επιβεβαιωθεί η παραγγελία σας - πραγματοποιείτε <strong>σε όλη την Ελλάδα</strong> με ταχυμεταφορά courier και η παράδοση γίνετε σε 1-3 εργάσιμες ημέρες στη διεύθυνση που θα δηλώσετε.<br />Το κόστος των μεταφορικών είναι <strong>3 ευρώ</strong> για παραγγελίες κάτω των 15 ευρώ.<br /><strong>Για παραγγελίες άνω των 15 ευρώ η αποστολή είναι δωρεάν Πανελλαδικά.</strong><br />Στις περιπτώσεις όπου η πληρωμή γίνεται με αντικαταβολή η <strong>χρέωση αντικαταβολής</strong> είναι <strong>2€</strong> επιπλέον.<br /><u><strong>Εξωτερικό:</strong></u><br />Σε όλες τις χώρες της Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης η <strong>χρέωση</strong> αποστολής είναι <strong>12€</strong> για παραγγελία βάρους έως 3 κιλών ανεξαρτήτου της ποσότητας παραγγελίας και φτάνει στην πόρτα σας μεταξύ 5 έως 8 εργάσιμων ημερών.<br />Για παραγγελίες άνω των <strong>150€ εντός Ευρωπαϊκής Ένωσης</strong> τα έξοδα αποστολής είναι <strong>ΔΩΡΕΑΝ!</strong><br />Στις υπόλοιπες χώρες η αποστολή γίνεται μέσω των δημόσιων ταχυδρομείων. Η χρέωση αποστολής καθώς και οι ημέρες παράδοσης εξαρτώνται από τη ζώνη αποστολής. Θα σας ενημερώσουμε μέσω e-mail ή τηλεφωνικά αφού ολοκληρώσετε τη διαδικασία παραγγελίας σας και πριν σας αποσταλούν τα εμπορεύματα.</p>' WHERE `language_id` = 2 AND `tab_id` = 2
```

which works.

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet one of those semicolons is really a Greek question mark (utf8 hex `CDBE`).  I point out the visual problem in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_natural_languages

Comment: Rick, I did a search-replace of **;** (Greek keyboard) with **;** (English keyboard) but still no luck :(